# How do I produce a Bézier curve with 4 points and without just using a website?

Tags: polynomials, binomial-coefficients, bezier-curve

I have these for points, (1,-2), (4,3), (12,3) and (15,-3), and I was wondering how do I make a model out of this, and how would this relate to polynomials and Pascal's triangle?

I have this formula:
$$B(t) = (1-t)^3 P_0 + 3(1-t)^2t P_1 + 3(1-t)t^2 P_2 + t^3 P_3$$
But I am still pretty confused

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you want the curve to pass through the specified points or what is the objective?

Comment: @mathreadler Vith the given (classical) formula, the curve will pass through extreme points $P_0,P_4$ and be guided by "handles $P_1$ and $P_2$ but not pass through them (see the picture in my answer).

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, yes I know that..., but I don't know if the person who asked the question knows that...

Comment: @mathreadler You are right. I had assumed maybe a larger knowledge from the OP.

Comment: What are you missing ? This *is* the formula. And how can you miss the relation to polynomials ???

Answer (score 1):

Simply, convert your expression into parametric equations, a first one dealing with the abscissas, the other with the ordinates

$$x=\color{red}{1}*(1-t)^3 *(1) + \color{red}{3}*(1-t)^2*t*(4) + \color{red}{3}*(1-t)*t^2*(12)+ \color{red}{1}*t^3*(15)$$

$$y=\color{red}{1}*(1-t)^3 *(-2) + \color{red}{3}*(1-t)^2*t*(3) + \color{red}{3}*(1-t)*t^2*(3)+ \color{red}{1}*t^3*(-3).$$

Then use a $plot(x,y)$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$ or an equivalent in your favorite programming language. See figure below.

**Remarks :**

1) Coefficients $\color{red}{1,3,3,1}$ constitute the third line of Pascal's triangle.

2) Imagine you had to draw a Bezier curve with endpoints $P_0$ and $P_4$ with **three** control points ("handles") $P_1,P_2,P_3$, you would use coefficients from the **fourth** line of Pascal's triangle in the folowing expression :

$$B(t) = \color{red}{1}(1-t)^4 t^0 P_0 + \color{red}{4}(1-t)^3 t^1 P_1 + \color{red}{6}(1-t)^2 t^2 P_2 + \color{red}{4}(1-t) t^3 P_3 + \color{red}{1}(1-t)^0 t^4 P_4$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick awnser! But how do i link the application of polynomials and pascals triangle into the awnser?

Comment: See coefficients in red. I have added a figure.

Comment: See my remark 2.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprhensive awnser it is very helpful, but my teacher has said we can not go to a degree higher than 3, is there another way to do this problem? I think some poeple have talked about Bi-nomial expansion and bernstein polynomials? I am really sorry for the inconvience, but thanks.